# Windows 10 always output audio over HDMI

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I want to attach a Sony 5.1 surround sytem to my mini-atx mainboard PC.

The only means of outputting 5.1 is the HDMI port of my Nvidia graphics card. The only input of 5.1 audio on the Sony system is through SPDIF.

I have a display attached over DVI and a TV attached over HDMI. The only way I see how this would work is to split the audio off the HDMI signal and convert it to SPDIF for the sony system.

This works somehow but only when the second screen (the TV) is enabled in Windows. This is not optimal as permanently mirroring the image to TV and display reduces the performance in some games. I want to be able to disable the image output of the HDMI output without disabling the sound output.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is what possible? It sounds like you need a sound card.  Your not going to be able to split the HDMI signal

Comment: What options do you have in the Playback section of the Sound settings? If you have more than one output device, they should be listed there.

Comment: @Ramhound I already am able, I bought a splitter. The question is in the last section: How can I output image signal over DVI and only audio over HDMI.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I have 3 DP, 1 DVI and 1 HDMI output. In the NVIDIA panel I can choose where the system sound should be output (DP or HDMI). But I want to be able to ONLY output audio over HDMI and image over DVI.

Comment: I am aware of what you have done, which I didn't say was impossible (although you might have taken in that way), what I said was impossible was the inability to split the audio signal.  You won't be able to do that.

Comment: @pythonimus No, what I meant was in the audio output settings, not the video output settings. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdV6s.png). What does your computer say it has here?

Comment: That settings screen is important, because I really don't want to disassemble my PC and hook it up to my TV and amp just to prove it works. ;)